# How do I iterate selected rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        For Each c In r
            sum = sum + 1
        Next c
    Next r
```

counts the num of rows but not cells

```
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        For Each c In r
            msgbox "val = " & c.Value
        Next c
    Next r
```

fails with 'Type mismatch'. What the fell? Where is the Selection object manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have not been explicit in what you want to itterate, `For Each c in r` is returning a multiple cell range.

You can see this if you break at `Sum = ...` and look at `c.Address` in the watch window.

To fix, try this

```
Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim Sum As Long
For Each r In Selection.Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        Sum = Sum + 1
    Next c
Next r
```

Or even this

```
Dim c As Range
Dim Sum As Long
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    Sum = Sum + 1
Next c
```

Comment: + 1 too fast LOL. Had to discard my post :)

Comment: `r.Cells`, just realized this myself. Thanks